# Perl - Performing boolean operations on JSON::XS::Boolean

Tags: perl

I am currently using the `JSON::XS::Boolean` to properly encode booleans into `JSON` format. Is there a way to perform boolean operations on these objects while preserving their ability to be encoded properly?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS::Boolean;

my $json = JSON::XS->new;

print($json->encode([JSON::XS::true])); # prints '[true]'
print($json->encode([!JSON::XS::false])); # prints ["1"] instead of '[false]'
```

Curiously, the `and` and `or` operators seem to behave properly:

```
print($json->encode([JSON::XS::false and JSON::XS::false])); # prints '[false]'
print($json->encode([JSON::XS::true && JSON::XS::true])); # prints '[true]'
print($json->encode([JSON::XS::false and JSON::XS::true])); # prints '[false]'

print($json->encode([JSON::XS::false || JSON::XS::false])); # prints '[false]'
print($json->encode([JSON::XS::true or JSON::XS::true])); # prints '[true]'
print($json->encode([JSON::XS::false || JSON::XS::true])); # prints '[true]'
```

Comment: I can't repro having "true" and "false" printed at all, so it must be version specific or something. However, try and see if `print not JSON::XS::false;` does what you want.

Comment: Note "*This module exists only to provide overload resolution for Storable and similar modules. It's only needed for compatibility with data serialised (by other modules such as Storable) that was decoded by JSON::XS versions before 3.0.*"

Comment: Given @SinanÜnür's comment and the posted answer, if you want the boolean printed as text, it may be more wise to do something like `print "true" if ! JSON::XS::false

Comment: @illusionist: [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) is just a wrapper around other JSON handling modules. Which one do you really use?

Comment: Note, one more time, "**SYNOPSIS** `# do not "use" yourself`". You are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want them to do, the objects returned by `JSON::XS::true` and `JSON::XS::false` would have to overload negation. They don't.

You could replace

```
!$p
```

with

```
$p ? JSON::XS::false : JSON::XS::true
```

Or you could normalize your data after the fact.

---

AND and OR happen to work because they always return one of their inputs.

```
Expression  Returns when  Returns when
            $p is true    $p is false
----------  ------------  ------------
$p || $q    $p            $q
$p && $q    $q            $p
```

A similar definition —one that returns an input— can't exist for NOT, so it returns a fresh value.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Should I add the negation overload to Cpanel::JSON::XS and JSON::PP?
Looks like it is needed. 
With JSON::XS the overloading is unfortunately broken.

Comment: @rurban, Don't know. That would break people doing `!!$val` to normalize *away* from objects.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off - your code doesn't do what you think it does. I get a sequence of 1s and zeros.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS::Boolean;

print(JSON::XS::true); # prints 'true'
print(!JSON::XS::false); # prints 1 instead of 'false'

print(JSON::XS::false and JSON::XS::false); # prints 'false'
print(JSON::XS::true && JSON::XS::true); # prints 'true'
print(JSON::XS::false and JSON::XS::true); # prints 'false'

print(JSON::XS::false || JSON::XS::false); # prints 'false'
print(JSON::XS::true or JSON::XS::true); # prints 'true'
print(JSON::XS::false || JSON::XS::true); # prints 'true'
```

Output:

```
11010011
```

However, you may get some odd behaviour when trying to convert 'boolean' types, because perl doesn't have a boolean type in the sense you are thinking. It has 'things that are true' and 'things that are false'.

"things that are false" are anything that is numerically zero. `undef`. An empty string.

And here's the thing - if you do a 'not true' and then *print* it, perl doesn't know which of the "things that are false" it should be.

So if you do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $value = !1;
print "Value is: \'",$value,"\'\n";
```

Perl assumes that because you're using it in a string context, you're wanting to do the stringified version.

But that's because `$value` is a [`dualvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#dualvar), with values of both `0` and `''`  - you can add to it numerically, and that will work too:

```
print "Value is: \'",$value+0,"\'\n";
```

Note - this doesn't work with 'normal' empty strings - you'll get `Argument "" isn't numeric in addition (+)`.

With your edited code - I can be pretty sure that it's the same thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS::Boolean;
use Scalar::Util qw ( isdual ); 
use Data::Dumper;

my $json = JSON::XS->new;

my $trueval = JSON::XS::true;
my $notfalse = !JSON::XS::false;

print Dumper $trueval;
print "\$trueval is a dualvar\n" if isdual($trueval);
print "Value = $trueval\n";

print Dumper $notfalse;
print "\$notfalse is a dualvar\n" if isdual($notfalse);
print "Value = $notfalse\n";

my $falseval = JSON::XS::false;
my $nottrue = !JSON::XS::true;

print Dumper $falseval;
print "\$falseval is a dualvar\n" if isdual($falseval);
print "Value = $falseval\n";

print Dumper $nottrue;
print "\$nottrue is a dualvar\n" if isdual($nottrue);
print "Value = $nottrue\n";
```

Note how `$notfalse` is no longer a blessed `JSON::PP::Boolean`?

Output:

```
$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' );
Value = 1
$VAR1 = 1;
$notfalse is a dualvar
Value = 1
$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' );
Value = 0
$VAR1 = '';
$nottrue is a dualvar
Value =
```

The `!` is casting it to the closest approximation of a perl boolean.

However the `||` doesn't need to, because perl evaluates the expression and returns *the result of the expression* without modifying it.

```
my $value = "some_text_here" || 0; 
print $value;
```

The `and`/`or` are "working" because perl tries not to return a boolean if it doesn't have to.

Comment: Even though your example produces `1`s and `0`s as output, it still preserves the `JSON::XS::Boolean` nature. ie. `print(ref(JSON::XS::true and JSON::XS::false) eq 'JSON::XS::Boolean'); # 1` however `print(ref(!JSON::XS::true) eq 'JSON::XS::Boolean'); # ''`

Comment: Yes. But what do you think the `!` is doing here? How do you think perl is negating `JSON::XS::true`? That's the root of your problem. Perl turns `!0` into `dualvar ( 1, "1")` and `!1` into `dualvar ( 0, '' );`

Comment: Please note all JSON modules map `\0` to false, and `\1` to `true`. So, `[\!JSON::XS::false]` **will** encode to `[true]`.